# The right way to make a continuously redrawn Metal NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, metal

I'm learning Metal and Cocoa and trying to make a boilerplate application as a platform for future experiments. As part of the process, I'm implementing a view which will redraw itself (or, more accurately, contents of its `CAMetalLayer`) on 60fps. Also for educational purposes Im avoiding `MTKView` (for "learning Cocoa part"). Here's an abbreviated code snippet of how I'm tackling the problem:

```
@implementation MyMetalView // which is a subclass of NSView

- (BOOL) isOpaque {
    return YES;
}

- (NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy) layerContentsRedrawPolicy {
    return NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;
}

- (CALayer *) makeBackingLayer {
    // create CAMetalLayer with default device
}

- (BOOL) wantsLayer {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) wantsUpdateLayer {
    return YES;
}

- (void) displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> cmdBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
    id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = [((CAMetalLayer *) layer) nextDrawable];

    [cmdBuffer enqueue];
    [cmdBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];

    // rendering

    [cmdBuffer commit];
}

@end

int main() {
    // init app, window and MyMetalView instance

    // invocation will call [myMetalViewInstance setNeedsDisplay:YES]
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1./60. invocation:setNeedsDisplayInvokation repeats:YES];

    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

Is it the right way to do what I want? Or have I chosen a long and not recommended approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strongly preferred to use `CVDisplayLink` rather than a generic `NSTimer` to drive animations that need to match the refresh rate of the display.

You'll want to create an ivar or property to hold a `CVDisplayLinkRef`:

```
CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink;
```

Then, when your view is going onto the screen and you want to start animating, you'll create, configure, and start your display link:

```
CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink);
CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, &MyDisplayLinkCallback, self);
CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink);
```

The display link callback should be a static function. It will be invoked at the beginning of the display's v-blank period (on modern displays where there is no physical v-blank, this still happens at a regular 60Hz cadence):

```
static CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void* displayLinkContext)
{

    [(MyMetalView *)displayLinkContext setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

When your view leaves the display, or if you want to pause, you can release the display link and nil it out:

```
CVDisplayLinkRelease(displayLink);
```

Comment: Can I just call directly my rendering code in `MyDisplayLinkCallback`?

Comment: I personally would leave my drawing in my `updateLayer` implementation or a method called by `updateLayer`. It's better to just use the callback function as a way to bounce back into your view implementation, rather than breaking up the code for the view across the class implementation and the callback (to a greater extent than necessary).

Comment: I've meant calling view's `updateLayer` from the callback instead of `setNeedsDisplay:YES`. If I understand correctly, `setNeedsDisplay:YES` only **schedules** view redraw sometime in the future, which will introduce additional latency, won't it?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to let the window server handle this kind of thing. In the same way you wouldn't call `drawRect:` directly, you shouldn't directly call `updateLayer` in an attempt to circumvent the update cycle. If you want to convince yourself (or prove me wrong), just print out the current time inside the callback function and `updateLayer`. I suspect you'll find there's much less than a frame of latency.

Answer (score 0):

following @warrenm solution adding dispatch_sync to refresh and other minor :

```
#import "imageDrawer.h"
#import "image/ImageBuffer.h"
#import "common.hpp"

@implementation imageDrawer {
    CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink;
}

CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void* displayLinkContext)
{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [(__bridge imageDrawer*)displayLinkContext setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    });
    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}

-(void)setContDisplay {
    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink);
    CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, &MyDisplayLinkCallback, (__bridge void*)self);
    CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink);
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [self setContDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    int w=rect.size.width, h=rect.size.height;
    // do the drawing...
}

@end
```